# BF compiler optimizations

Tags: c, compiler-optimization

I wrote simple brainfuck2c translator. I have added slight optimizations (for pointer moves), but I think about optimizing additions/subtractions, for example we have code like `++++` that would translate into `mem[0]+=1;mem[0]+=1;mem[0]+=1;mem[0]+=1;`. My goal is make my interpreter optimize additions and subtraction to output following code for this: `mem[0]+=4;`. Code i wrote (with only arrows optimization); I know it's not "c++ style" but i am C programmer. So how to implement addition/subtranction optimizations? I have googled somewhat, but i found only python solutions, and i didnt use them because i don't understand them, and solutions using external libraries (e.g. LLVM).

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    int pos = 0;
    int amount = 0;
    int brackets = 0;
    if(argc!=2)exit(0);
    FILE* f = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if(f!=NULL){
        char* outbuffer = malloc(1024*1024*1024);
        char c = fgetc(f);
        strcpy(outbuffer, "int getch(void);\nvoid putch(int);\nint main(){\n");
        while(!feof(f)){
            if(c == '<'){
                if(pos==0)pos=65536;
                else pos--;
            }
            if(c == '>'){
                if(pos==65536)pos=0;
                else pos++;
            }
            if(c == '['){
                brackets++;
                sprintf(outbuffer, "while(mem[%d]){", pos);
            }
            if(c == ']'){
                brackets--;
                sprintf(outbuffer, "}");
            }
            if(c == '+'){
                sprintf(outbuffer, "mem[%d]+=1;", pos);
            }
            if(c == '-'){
                sprintf(outbuffer, "mem[%d]-=1;", pos);
            }
            if(c == '.'){
                sprintf(outbuffer, "putch(mem[%d]);", pos);
            }if(c == '.'){
                sprintf(outbuffer, "mem[%d] = getch();", pos);
            }
            c = fgetc(f);
        }
        if(brackets == 1){
            printf("Compilation succesfull. ");
            printf("Generated Code:\n%s", outbuffer);
            free(outbuffer);
        }
        else{
            printf("Comilation fault. Unbalanced brackets.");
            free(outbuffer);
        }
    }
}
```

Okay, i have found an answer. I created separate functions; It can be helpful when writing a compiler with C backend; Thanks to Gene for help.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int minus(FILE* f){
    int c;
    int amount = 0;
    while ((c = getc(f)) == '-')
        amount++;
    ungetc(c, f);
    return amount;
}

int plus(FILE* f){
    int c;
    int amount = 0;
    while ((c = getc(f)) == '+')
        amount++;
    ungetc(c, f);
    return amount;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    int pos = 0;
    int brackets = 0;
    if(argc!=2)exit(0);
    int amount = 1;
    FILE* f = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if(f!=NULL){
        char* outbuffer = (char*)malloc(1024*1024);
        strcpy(outbuffer, "int getch(void);\nvoid putch(int);\nint main(){\n");
        while(!feof(f)){
            printf("Iterating.");
            char c = fgetc(f);
            if(c == '<'){
                if(pos==0)pos=65536;
                else pos--;
            }
            if(c == '>'){
                if(pos==65536)pos=0;
                else pos++;
            }
            if(c == '['){
                brackets++;
                sprintf(outbuffer, "%swhile(mem[%d]){",outbuffer,pos);
            }
            if(c == ']'){
                brackets--;
                sprintf(outbuffer, "%s}", outbuffer);
            }
            if(c == '+'){
                amount = plus(f)+1;
                sprintf(outbuffer, "%smem[%d]+=%d;",outbuffer, pos, amount);
            }
            if(c == '-'){
                amount = minus(f)+1;
                sprintf(outbuffer, "%smem[%d]-=%d;",outbuffer, pos, amount);
            }
            if(c == '.'){
                sprintf(outbuffer, "%sputch(mem[%d]);",outbuffer, pos);
            }
            if(c == '.'){
                sprintf(outbuffer, "%smem[%d]=getch();",outbuffer, pos);
            }
        }
        if(brackets == 0){
            printf("Compilation succesfull. ");
            printf("Generated Code:\n%s", outbuffer);
            free(outbuffer);
        }
        else{
            printf("Comilation fault. Unbalanced brackets.");
            free(outbuffer);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unless you're running into severe problems, this question would be more relevant when posed on codereview.stackexchange.com. That said: learn about `switch`.

Comment: Since you tagged your post as C++, you should read about `std::cout` and `std::cin`.

Comment: Also, prefer to use `std::vector` rather than a dynamic array.

Comment: @Thomas I have tagged as C, but mat removed this.

Comment: What's with all the C idioms? `sprintf`? `strcpy`? Really? We actually moved on from this unsafe stuff back in the 1990s :)

Comment: Okay, its now pure C.

Comment: Is this even correct? It seems to assume that the current position can be known statically, but that isn't true due to loops and such. Also you can more easily do optimizations if you represent a program in memory instead of trying to do it on the fly while "streaming" it, but you *could* implement some tricks that way..

Comment: It's position on the tape.

Comment: I thought that question was C++, so I made [a quick prototype](http://pastebin.com/WvWyD0NP) rewritten in C++ which includes the optimization. NB: [Here](https://godbolt.org/g/BvNroh) is the assembly generated by GCC7. Unless you want to save disk space or compile time, I also wouldn't be surprised the C compiler would do this optimization on its own.

Comment: I will look at it, but I actually look for alghorith counting pluses at current position, thanks for help. I'll try to translate it somewhat to C, because i use tcc as backend.

Comment: you just have to know I counted and skipped subsequent +, -, < and >.

Comment: @Joel but that's the problem. A loop can move the data position multiple times. For example `[>]`. You don't statically know the value of the data pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general approach that compilers use for these kinds of simple optimizations is to generate code lazily.

Rather than emit code for a given HLL feature immediately, it's stored in a convenient data structure that serves as a buffer. After each new chunk of code is added, the optimizer inspects the buffer and applies pattern matching rewrite rules that reduce the cost of the buffered code without changing its meaning.

In your case, the rule would look like `X += m; X += n; --> X += (m+n);`. I.e., rewrite two increments of the same l-value as a single increment by the sum of the original two.

Another trivial example: `X += 0 --> <nothing>`. I.e., erase increments by zero.

Code is kept in the buffer as long as it might yet match one of the rules.  When that's impossible, it's finally emitted and deleted.

The buffer is sometimes called a "peephole" into the instruction output stream. Therefore this method of improving code is called "peephole optimization". You can learn a lot by searching for this term.

There are lots of schemes for implementing the buffer.  For expressions, a symbolic operand stack can work well. For statements, the usual approach is to store a FIFO queue of 2- or 3- address code, an abstract representation of output code.

Comment: I just have looked at this, and it can be helpful. I am just looking for alghoritm counting pluses. This code I made so far: `amount = 1; while ((c = getc(f)) == '+' && c != EOF) amount++; fseek(f , -1, SEEK_CUR);`

Comment: @Joel The `&& c != EOF` is redundant. If `c` is equal to `'+'`, then it  can never be equal to `EOF`.  Using `fseek` to "unread" one character is not a great idea. See the documentation on `ungetc()`.  Also, consider reading the whole input into a string. Then you don't need either of these hacks. You can just maintain an index or pointer into the input string. You're allocating a full gigabyte for the output. This seems like bigtime overkill. A megabyte of input and a megabyte of output would seem more than sufficient for BF purposes.

Comment: @Joel  Other details: Rather than `plus` and `minus`, it would be better style to use a single function and pass `'+`` or `'-'` as a char parameter. The `(char*)` cast on `malloc()` is unnecessary and a bad idea. That's a C++ thing. The advice someone else gave about using a `switch` rather than the `if` chain is good advice. Note: Your functions implement a simple kind of lazy code emission, so you're doing what I suggested. For more advanced ideas, see http://www.iwriteiam.nl/Ha_bf2c_c.txt